# Stored procedure works fine and does not return null in SQL Server, but in VS it returns null

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio, stored-procedures, null

I'm trying to get just a single value from the database. 
In SQL-Server it works fine and I get a value which is not null. But whenever I try to do it from VS, "status" variable in the code always becomes null even if it gets the parameter and connects the database correctly. 
Here is my code:

```
string id = textboxOrderDate.SelectedValue;

SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["iremConnection"].ConnectionString);
con.Open();

SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT_ORDERSTATUS_BY_ORDERID", con);

command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

SqlParameter paramID = new SqlParameter("@ORDERID", id);

command.Parameters.Add(paramID);

string status= (string)command.ExecuteScalar();
//string status=command.ExecuteScalar().ToString();

con.Close();
```

I also tried using a dataadapter to fill the dataset with a datatable to retrieve the value I want. But, unfortunately datatable row count is equal to 0. My stored procedure works fine I do not understand why it does not work the same way with the VS. Here is my stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SELECT_ORDERSTATUS_BY_ORDERID]
@ORDERID VARCHAR(50)
AS
SELECT dbo.OrderTable.Status
FROM OrderTable
WHERE @ORDERID=OrderID
```

Comment: Are you sure you are passing the correct OrderID?

Comment: Yes I'm. I send the same OrderID as the parameter to the stored procedure in SQL Server and it works fine.

Comment: Temporarily alter your stored procedure and hard code the OrderID value. What do you get in your program?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I found the problem. I was using DateTime type as OrderID and it was not matching with the one stored in the database. Database stores it with zeros at the end so it was not matching what my c# code sends.

Thank you everyone.